# Gradle sync failed: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 p

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While using Android Studio 3.0 (canay7) my computer crashed. I restarted Windows and Android Studio.

My project Gradle sync failed and is now showing the message:

> "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 p".

The point is that I have never changed my Gradle files.

I've invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio, but it didn't work. 
I have no idea what caused this problem. Can anyone help me?

Here's my Gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. File a report!

Comment: I have just encountered this error myself. Is this a bug or is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

Try to Clean Build the Project.It worked for Me

Happy Coding

Answer (score -2):

Just clean app
Step 1 go to Build
Step 2 clean project

its work perfectly

Comment: Remove this duplicate answer